# remove rows of specified levels of factor from dataframe

Tags: r

I have what may be a very simple problem to solve in R, but I've been struggling with it for a while without finding an adequate solution.

From the following dataframe, I just need to fully remove any row that contains 'U' for Sex, whilst also removing the level 'U' from factor Sex. And I would also like the ability to remove any ID of my choosing by specifying a vector of ID numbers. My actual dataset is much larger than this.

```
datf <- read.table(text = "ID   Sex Mor SITE
                           110   F   W    1
                           111   M   W    2
                           112   M   B    4
                           135   F   W    3
                           556   M   B    1
                           557   U   B    1
                           558   M   W    2",
                   header = TRUE)
```

I thought I would be able to work this out, but I have tried various methods suggested on this website such as droplevels- but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks very much in advance for your help!

Comment: what  `R` code have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

- Remove rows with `Sex == 'U'` and drop level

  ```
  datf <- droplevels(datf[!datf$Sex == 'U',])
  str(datf)

  'data.frame':   6 obs. of  4 variables:
   $ ID  : int  110 111 112 135 556 558
   $ Sex : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 2 2 1 2 2
   $ Mor : Factor w/ 2 levels "B","W": 2 2 1 2 1 2
   $ SITE: int  1 2 4 3 1 2
  ```
- Remove any row where ID in vector

  ```
  datf <- datf[!(datf$ID %in% c(110, 558)),]
  datf

     ID Sex Mor SITE
  2 111   M   W    2
  3 112   M   B    4
  4 135   F   W    3
  5 556   M   B    1
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much for this!